# Avoiding removing undesired characters inside a string prefix

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple regex to remove undesired chars(like numbers for instance) from a string:

```
preg_replace(/[^a-z_]/, '', $str);
```

But now it must keep a prefix that contains some of those chars that were being removed. That prefix format consists of an alpha char followed by four numbers(prefix exemple: `b1234`). String example:

```
b7001_cp_parc_venc_fluxo
```

So i tried to add a non-capturing group for that prefix, but i can't make it to work. Attempted to use things like:

```
(?:b[0-9]{4})[^a-z_]
```

But it stops removing numeric chars in the whole string, for example.

Comment: Try `/^b[0-9]{4}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-z_]/`. Did you mean `b7001_cp_parc_venc_fluxo` should remain unchanged after `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are *removing* the found matches, you can also use

```php
preg_replace('~^b[0-9]{4}\K|[^a-z_]+~', '', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bdIwmq/1).

*Details*

- `^b[0-9]{4}\K` - finds `b` and four digits at the start of a string and then [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discards the matched text and thus nothing gets replaced
- `|` - or
- `[^a-z_]+` - matches one or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters or underscore and these matches are removed.

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Hl9Lt):

```php
$string = 'b7001_cp---_parc1323546_venc.,?><_     fluxo';
echo preg_replace('/^b[0-9]{4}\K|[^a-z_]/', '', $string);
// => b7001_cp_parc_venc_fluxo
```

Comment: You got it perfectly right! I didn't knew about `\K`, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One option is making use of [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

```
b[0-9]{4}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-z_]
```

- `b[0-9]{4}(*SKIP)(*F)` Match what you want to avoid
- `|` Or
- `[^a-z_]` Match any char other than `a-z` or `_`

You can also repeat the character class 1+ times `[^a-z_]+` to get a single match for consecutive characters.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uz6rnJ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/mamTB)

Example

```
$pattern = "/b[0-9]{4}(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-z_]/";
$str = "b7001_cp_parc_venc_fluxo_1234";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

Output

```
b7001_cp_parc_venc_fluxo_
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As `\K` in @Wiktor answer, I also didn't knew about skip fail!